# Is there a way in python to minimize a bivariate function which uses a for loop to obtain values for constants?

Tags: python, for-loop, optimization, scipy

I have a function `eqn` which I want minimized by changing the values of two variables (floats), `a` and `b`. However, `eqn` uses a for loop to obtain values for constants, which are unrelated to `a` and `b`, from the lists `list1` and `list2`, as shown:

```
def eqn(a, b, list1, list2):
    value = 0
    for i in range(len(list1):
        value = value + ((a - (1 - exp(- c * list1[i]) - list2[i]) ** 2)
    return value
```

I am unsure how to include the iterative inclustion of list members as constants in scipy.optimize.minimize, and I can't find any mention of it in the documentation

I have already got a nested for-loop to manually minimize the function by brute force w.r.t. `a` and `b`, but I cannot get to the precision level that I need before running into a mem error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To be sure I have understood: are `list1` and `list2` two lists holding test values for  `a` and `b`?

Comment: Nope, they are lists that hold constants and are completely separate to `a` and `b`

Comment: have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12200114/two-dimensional-optimization-minimization-in-python-using-scipy-optimize

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I have yes, but I'm still confused as to how to implemenent constants into an equation to be minimized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [minimize docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) the function to be minimized must be in the form:

> fun(x, *args) -> float
>   where x is an 1-D array with shape (n,) and args is a tuple of the fixed parameters needed to completely specify the function.

This means that your constants should be grouped in a single list (not two lists), and your variables too. For example:

```
def eqn(x, *param):
    value = 0
    ll = len(param)//2
    for i in range(ll):
        value = value + ((x[0] - (1 - math.exp(- x[1] * param[i]) - param[i+ll]) ** 2))
    return value
```

Here `x` is a list (so `x[0]` would be your `a` and `x[1]` your `b`) and `param` is your two lists concatenated: `list1 + list2`.

Note the asterisk: to use this function by itself (not as a `minimize` argument) you must do:

```
vars = (1, 2)
consts = (3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
res = eqn(vars, *consts)
```

but defined this way, is eligible as an argument for `minimize`.

If you do not know the asterisk notation in function definition, you can find more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters) or in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/dev/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists).

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up! I wasn't sure how to parse the constants for the equation